# Writing pseudocode with dummy value

Tags: python, algorithm, pseudocode

An pseudocode is required to input  a series of numbers from the keyboard and to ensure that they are in ascending order even though they need not be consecutive.The number may be positive or negative and will end with a dummy value of 9999.

This is a python code I wrote and it works ok,

```
li=[]
num=int(raw_input("Enter number"))
while num!=9999:
    li.append(num)
    num=int(raw_input("Enter number"))
new=0   
print "Entered sequence is "
print li
j=0
while j<len(li):
    for i in range(len(li)-1):
        value1=li[i]
        value2=li[i+1]

        if (value1>value2):
            new=li[i]
            li[i]=li[i+1]
            li[i+1]=new
    j+=1
print "ordered list is "
print li
```

But I have problem in writing this as an algorithm.

This is my tried algorithm:

```
Main
    li      list
    num     integer
    new=0,j=0       integer
    Begin   
        num=INPUT num.
        while num<>9999.
            append num to li.
            num=INPUT num.
        ENDWHILE.
    DISSPLAY "Entered Sequence is".
    OUTPUT li.
    while j<(length of li).
        FOR i=0 to (length of li-2).
        value1=i th element of li
        value2=(i+1) th element of li
            if (value1>value2):
                new=value1
                value1=value2
                value2=new
            ENDIF
        END FOR
        j=j+1
    ENDWHILE
    DISPLAY "ORDERED LIST IS"
    DISPLAY li
    END
END
```

Can I use "**list**" in an algorithm because I think objects as "list" do not appear in every programming language.And shouldn't  algorithm be a general code.Same way is it allowed to use arrays in writing an algorithm

And **Is it okay to say "value1=ith element in li"**?

And how to show that I am assigning the value entered from keyboard to the variable "num"

Comment: You are not writing the algorithm, but pseudocode. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: There are various conventions and no one correct answer. I have previously tried to be consistent with the style from a textbook (e.g. Introduction to Algorithms) but it really depends who you are writing this for.

Comment: Agree I think your Python code is pretty unambiguous even if the reader did not know Python and mostly works fine as pseudocode. The only thing I might consider for a general reader is that they might not know what `range` does.

Comment: So is it okay to use lists ,tuples,dictionaries in a pseudocode, even if they are not common to all programming languages

Answer (score 1):

*(This was originally a comment)*

You seem to miss what the point of pseudo code is. Pseudo code is neither standardized nor somewhat defined. In general it is just a *code-like* representation of an algorithm, while maintaining a high level and readability. You can write pseudo code in whatever form you like. Even real Python code could be considered pseudo code. That being said, there are no thing disallowed in pseudo code; you can even write prose to explain something that happens. For example in the inner-most loop, you could just write *“swap value1 and value2”*.

This is approximately how I would transform your Python code into pseudo-code. I tend to leave out all language specific stuff and focus just on the actual algorithmic parts.

```
Input:
    list: Array of input numbers

FOR j = 0 to length(list):
    FOR i = 0 to length(list)-1:
        if list[i] > list[i+1]:
            Swap list[i] and list[i+1]
OUTPUT ordered list
```

---

> So is it okay to use lists, tuples, dictionaries in a pseudocode, even if they are not common to all programming languages?

Absolutely! In more complex algorithms you will even find things like *“Get minimum spanning tree for XY”* which would be a whole different problem for which again multiple different solutions exist. Instead of specifying a specific solution you are keeping it open to the actual implementation which algorithm is to be used for that. It usually does not matter for the algorithm you are currently describing. Maybe later when you analyze your algorithm, you might mention things like *“There are algorithms known for this who can do this in O(log n)”* or something, so you just use that to continue.

Comment: Thanks for the expalnation